# How to grant a "no-root-user" rights to start/stop/restart mysql server on suse machine?

Tags: mysql, privileges

Is it possible to grant priviliges to a "no-root-user" to start and/stop/restart the mysql server on a suse machine?

The goal is to make it for a developer possible to tune a mysql server/database and track some error down, which occure while an application corresponds with the mysql server. The server is on a SUSE machine.

At the moment the user is in the group `mysql` which grants him access to the logfile in `/var/log/mysqld.log`. But after tweaking the `my.cnf` he was not able to restart the server. So it seams, that he needs more rights then only beeing in the group `mysql`.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Additional question:
Are there more priviliges that should be granted to him to garanty his workflow, while working and administrating the mysql server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Change the setuid bit of the mysqld executable and the ownership of the executable file to the mysql account, besides adding the required user in the group `mysql` for making him have access to the files on the filesystem.
- Use `visudo -f /etc/sudoers` and grant him permission to execute the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start` and `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql stop` as two separate commands in the COMMAND list and in the execution part, grant the user to execute both the commands as user (mysql).
  For more information on sudoers, refer to the sudoers man page. `man sudoers`.
- Apart from that, from a `mysqld` perspective, he may need additional grants on the Database server/databases to guarantee his workflow requirements, like tuning the tables, creating & dropping databases and tables, and performing some monitoring related activities with in a mysql session, etc.

Comment: How do you expect add the acction into the sudoers without being a root?.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't possible. I don't know of any way to grant a user rights to start and stop daemons; I don't think there is one. For working with the mysql server, you can create a user for him with all rights to the mysql db

Comment: Incorrect: See the above answer re: `sudo`